# How to create arrayformula sequence number separated by comma in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How to create arrayformula sequence number separated by comma in google spreadsheets
expected results is in column B

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1,2,3,4,5 |
| 2 | 1,2 |
| 3 | 1,2,3 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A1))))
```

- When you use this formula, please put this to a cell "B1" and drag down it.
- The flow of this formula is as follows.

  1. Create a1Notation of cells using `"A1:A"&A1` using `INDIRECT`.
  2. Retrieve row numbers from the a1Notation using `ROW`.
  3. Join the row numbers with `,` using `JOIN`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

When you want to put all result values using one formula, unfortunately, I couldn't find the formula using the built-in functions. In that case, I would like to propose to a custom function as follows. When you use this, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet.

And, please put a formula of `=SAMPLE(A1:A)` to a cell "B1". By this, the result values are put to the column "B" using the values of column "A".

```
const SAMPLE = v => v.map(([e]) => e && !isNaN(e) ? [...Array(e)].map((_, i) => i + 1).join(",") : "");
```

#### References:

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)
- [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: @UAQ  Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TEXTJOIN()` with `SEQUENCE()` function.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SEQUENCE(A1))
```

You can also use this functions in desktop `Excel365`

Comment: `JOIN(",",SEQUENCE(A1))` is enough